# Visualizing an initially normalized vector on the complex plane that goes from an angle x to an angle of i*x

Tags: complex-analysis

Choose a vector on the complex plane that is represented in the conventional form of $Z = (a + i \space b )$. Have the "length" associated with this complex number be 1. Set the rotation of the complex number as $\frac{\pi}{4}$ radians above the real axis; to wit, have:

$$ Z_0 = cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) + i\space sin(\frac{\pi}{4}) $$

Now change the angle from ($\frac{\pi}{4}$) to ($ i \space \frac{\pi}{4}$). The expression then becomes:

$$ Z_1 = cos(\frac{i\space\pi}{4}) + i\space sin(\frac{i\space\pi}{4}) $$

In general, what transformation will you see happen to this vector on the complex plane? How does the length, angle, and location of the vector change? Also, can this transformation from $Z_0$ to $Z_1$ be represented as two functions $f$ and $g$ on the real and imaginary parts of $Z_0$? Concretely:

$$ Z_1 = f \circ Real(Z_0) + i \times(g \circ Imaginary(Z_0)) $$

I computed this value and had $Z_0$ equal to ($0.71 + i \space 0.71$) and $Z_1$ equal to ($0.46 + i \space 0$). I am stuck on visualizing the general transformation of what any generalized vector at angle ($x$) is subjected to when the angle goes to ($i \space x$)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It seems you have not provided your attempts on the problem. Can you provide some context or where you are getting stuck? Otherwise your question will probably be closed.

Comment: Please take a little more care when choosing tags - four of the five tags you'd applied to the questions were not appropriate.

Comment: Note that in the polar form of a complex number, the angle chosen must be a positive real number; while $\cos (i\pi/4), \sin (i\pi/4)$ are defined, they mean something very different.

Comment: @PCeltide, Thank you, what do they mean then? I'm very curious about what they are.